# Conditional ui:include and preserve layout in JSF

Tags: jsf, layout, conditional-statements, facelets, uiinclude

is it possible in JSF facelets to do a conditional `ui:include` and preserve the layout of the parent (the including xhtml)?

Example: I have a form which has always some basic attributes rendered in a panelgrid with 4 columns (label, input, label input). Now I have some type specific form input elements. For each type specific form part I created a separate xhtml. For this the specific attributes have to be conditionally included after the basic attributes. Unfortunately the `ui:include` has no `rendered` attribute. So I have to wrap something around the `ui:include`. This unfortunately "overrides" my layout set by the including parent which defines 4 columns. I want to render the specific attributes in this 4 column panelGrid without starting a new layout element which is vanishing my layout. Is there a possibility in JSF to achieve this?

Regards
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `c:if` statement wrapping the `ui:include` element to conditionally render it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using now primefaces p:panelGrid and the tags p:row and p:column and added the rendered condition to p:row. I try to avoid c tags because I had some strange behaviour in the past with it. But it could be a solution anyway.

Comment: That's indeed another solution.